# Time series analysis: seasonal differencing

Tags: time-series

I'm using `nsdiffs()` to test if seasonal differencing is required.
This is my time series:

```
(28.35  ,
51.89   ,
37.26   ,
48.22   ,
30.93   ,
43.54   ,
35.30   ,
59.45   ,
49.41   ,
65.61   ,
36.59   ,
51.25   ,
31.42   ,
53.16   ,
39.41   ,
64.45   ,
43.94   ,
79.36   ,
52.93   ,
74.99   ,
55.03   ,
86.93   ,
41.69   ,
62.77   ,
41.29   ,
59.95   ,
40.07   ,
66.13   ,
47.15   ,
85.12   ,
74.44   ,
76.42   ,
49.17   ,
82.66   ,
49.88   ,
70.98   ,
52.83   ,
75.85   ,
61.40   ,
85.20   ,
61.99   ,
90.68   ,
48.05   ,
74.20   ,
41.70   ,
68.00   ,
46.41   ,
82.23   ,
62.18   ,
88.65   ,
65.21   ,
100.90  ,
46.63   ,
83.53   ,
56.57   ,
108.87  ,
51.01   ,
80.15   ,
57.03   ,
87.91   ,
62.41   ,
96.11   ,
71.41   ,
82.08   ,
62.50   ,
88.52   ,
60.53   ,
100.15  ,
67.74   ,
111.88  ,
74.64   ,
138.64  ,
97.88   ,
153.88  ,
111.34  ,
176.40  ,
67.57   ,
111.95  ,
72.36   ,
118.85  ,
82.19   ,
136.88  ,
84.95   ,
160.58  ,
64.13   ,
111.32  ,
64.65   ,
113.82  ,
74.75   ,
118.76  ,
86.28   ,
166.36  ,
71.82   ,
119.83  ,
67.64   ,
116.17  ,
77.83   ,
130.64  ,
95.23   ,
149.84  ,
115.97  ,
189.69  ,
96.35   ,
137.51  ,
82.04   ,
139.19  ,
70.68   ,
135.22  ,
69.84   ,
105.70  ,
65.47   ,
111.47  ,
63.71   ,
108.23  ,
66.81   ,
117.96  ,
86.82   ,
141.74  ,
71.97   ,
122.65  ,
89.35   ,
133.97  ,
110.07  ,
159.18  ,
117.40  ,
196.90  ,
167.69  ,
244.75  ,
85.43   ,
135.54  ,
70.51   ,
118.30  ,
78.83   ,
139.85  ,
108.57  ,
162.66  ,
139.03  ,
203.72  ,
94.37   ,
135.92  ,
80.35   ,
128.63  ,
90.20   ,
157.56  ,
112.91  ,
177.07  ,
147.28  ,
221.67  ,
90.86   ,
142.66  ,
93.96   ,
157.89  ,
121.50  ,
200.35  ,
140.08  ,
306.36  ,
187.86  ,
171.39  ,
113.52  ,
174.20  ,
108.89  ,
170.53  ,
121.49  ,
193.65  ,
148.72  ,
210.61  ,
168.46  ,
250.40  ,
213.54  ,
181.78  ,
126.56  ,
190.46  ,
137.85  ,
226.25  ,
148.68  ,
235.04  ,
170.39  ,
275.04  ,
106.68  ,
163.24  ,
109.15  ,
186.46  ,
129.33  ,
156.18  ,
91.03   ,
159.87  ,
119.43  ,
164.51  ,
92.84   ,
145.00  ,
87.02   ,
156.55  ,
92.76   ,
140.93  ,
102.72  ,
143.41  ,
92.11   ,
159.72  ,
96.44   ,
156.98  ,
151.38  ,
221.12  ,
174.89  ,
242.53  ,
117.66  ,
163.44  ,
111.25  ,
169.58  ,
103.27  ,
163.09  ,
105.62  ,
186.64  ,
124.75  ,
145.65  ,
108.31  ,
165.30  ,
101.91  ,
156.55  ,
101.72  ,
147.11  ,
106.25  ,
185.68  ,
146.83  ,
192.05  ,
101.46  ,
153.65  ,
105.91  ,
170.10  ,
97.07   ,
165.05  ,
106.06  ,
167.25  ,
102.68  ,
197.21  ,
99.19   ,
169.58  ,
106.66  ,
196.44  ,
103.46  ,
165.62  ,
108.77  ,
188.32  ,
117.03  ,
241.48  ,
171.60  ,
189.78  ,
110.79  ,
166.22  ,
116.14  ,
229.75  ,
144.17  ,
205.75  ,
137.51  ,
216.51  ,
111.98  ,
186.34  ,
138.92  ,
218.35  ,
172.29  ,
271.53  ,
143.24  ,
272.35  ,
274.90  ,
232.97  ,
238.00  ,
234.88  ,
172.19  ,
260.82  ,
143.12  ,
217.38  ,
136.56  ,
209.91  ,
144.57  ,
253.58  ,
171.79  ,
264.78  ,
189.01  ,
298.97  ,
231.23  ,
315.29  ,
198.05  ,
318.52  ,
183.21  ,
232.33  ,
161.40  ,
261.82  ,
145.56  ,
218.09  ,
140.13  ,
215.00  ,
154.87  ,
293.88  ,
164.71  ,
256.85  ,
192.69  ,
306.87  ,
255.16  ,
382.27  ,
298.13  ,
438.22  ,
183.88  ,
279.56  ,
217.82  ,
371.55  ,
269.81  ,
383.89  ,
211.72  ,
330.02  ,
217.97  ,
312.64  ,
227.47  ,
329.25  ,
238.65  ,
363.80  ,
280.39  ,
453.38  ,
363.84  ,
486.65  ,
647.67  ,
534.41  ,
219.69  ,
292.16  ,
209.73  ,
336.33  ,
226.43  ,
336.23  ,
249.48  ,
359.84  ,
188.05  ,
307.73  ,
231.67  ,
330.43  ,
252.22  ,
379.30  ,
293.54  ,
413.67  ,
384.64  ,
515.86  ,
482.36  ,
438.12)
```

Lets call this time series `sales`.
When I try to do that:

```
ns <- nsdiffs(ts(sales))
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in nsdiffs(sales) : Non seasonal data
```

Could anybody please explain to me why?
Thanks!

Comment: @forecaster, you beat me to it in editing :)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem perhaps was that the argument supplied to the function `nsdiffs` did not have an attribute `frequency` extractable using the function `frequency`. If you supply a simple vector to the function `nsdiffs`, the function will try extracting the frequency, fail and emit the error message "Non seasonal data". You need to supply a time series object that has the attribute `frequency`, such as a `ts` object (and you have to specify the frequency when creating a `ts` object, which you failed to do), then it should work. This can be seen by looking at the code of the function `nsdiffs`: simply type `nsdiffs` in R and press "Enter". However, the need to supply an object with a `frequency` attribute is not documented in sufficient detail in the [help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/ndiffs), which may be a little confusing.